# Loading an HTML file into a DIV with a link

Tags: javascript, html

There are several topics on this, but none that completely answer my question.

I would like to be able to have a link which loads a whole HTML file into a DIV.

This, for example, will load just text into my "MainBack" DIV. It works fine:

```
<a href="#computing" onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = '<p>1</p>';">Computing</a>
```

but I would like to load an entire file into it like this:

```
<a href="#computing" onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = 'HTML FILE';">Computing</a>
```

Any advice? I'm pretty new to this!

Answer (score 10):

You can use an `<iframe>` to do just that:

```
<iframe src="link.html" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/WFTnu/1/)**

Code:

```
<a href="#computing" onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = '<iframe src=\'http://www.google.com\' scrolling=\'no\' frameborder=\'0\' width=\'100%\' height=\'600px\'></iframe>'">Computing</a>
```

Or you could use **[lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)** to do it in a really pretty manner...

It will display; photos, videos, HTML... basically anything you want.

Comment: How should this be formatted? Should I keep it inside '' ? If so, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MarkBrewerton Are you loading an External file or simply a load of HTML code?

Comment: A load of HTML code, it just seems tidier to load an external file.

Comment: Yeah you are right, best bet is to put it into an external HTML file, then call the `<iframe>` with the onclick event, that or use lightbox which then gives you a nice translucent pop-up

Comment: Out of interest, how would I just load some HTML? I seem to be able to load something like <p>1</p> but not stuff like YouTube embeds.

Comment: and is this how I should do an iFrame? <a href="#computing" onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = '<iframe src="test.html"></iframe>'">Computing</a>
That doesn't seem to work. The link looks like this if I do: '">Computing

Comment: `<a href="#computing" onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = '<iframe src=\'test.html\'></iframe>'">Computing</a>`

Comment: Do you know how to make the iFrame fill the DIV and remove the border/scroll bars?

Comment: @MarkBrewerton - Sure mam use this: `<a href="#computing"  onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = '<iframe  src=\'http://www.google.com\' scrolling=\'no\' frameborder=\'0\' width=\'100%\'  height=\'600px\'></iframe>'">Computing</a>` change the height to whatever you want

Answer (score 7):

Using the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/load/) ajax API you can grab the content of a particular tag inside the document from some URL:

```
<a href="#computing" 
   onclick="$('#MainBack').load('/path/file.html body')"
>
    Computing
</a>
```

Important:

1. `#MainBack` is the ID of the placeholder tag in your parent document
2. `/path/file.html` id the URL for the document you want to load data from
3. `body` is the tag holding the content you want to load.

What can go wrong:

- check #1 above, does your parent document has a tag with the exact ID you are using in the ajax call?
- check #2, can you load the URL in a separate browser window?
- if you can load the URL, use the "view source" option to inspect the HTML source and make sure you have the selector you are using in #3 above. Perhaps the content you want is being generated dynamically from JavaScript instead of being served by the HTTP server, in this case use the `iframe` solution from the other answer.
- check the JavaScript console and look for some message about cross-domain issues, CSRF, CORS, etc. If the content is from another domain you may stumble upon the browser security rules; this is a whole new can of worms and I will not cover the possible solutions here, take the error message from the console and google for it.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery in the HTML header section? Please read docs and see examples in the given link.

Comment: It should work. This one is much cleaner solution than the iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#computing" onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = '<iframe src=\'http://www.google.com\'></iframe>'">Computing</a>
```

## --> [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/Yn659/) <--

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load a complete html page in to another. By that, I mean that you cant have a markup like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <html>
      ...
      </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe thing you are searching for is an iframe? A small "window" in your page to another page?

If iframe doesn't suit you, take a look at this Jquery function which loads a html from other source in your specified selector: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: How about if I just wanted to load a part of an HTML page? Something like this: <p>In computing I learn programming, along with the theory behind computers and logic.</p><br /><p>Here is a video about the TCP/IP stack which I made with a friend:</p><iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oeGt3exwqoE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

**You can load HTML content from another file via jQuery ".load()" method.**

First, in the HEAD section of your main html file, you need to include this line to access the jQuery libraries' functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Second, add this code inside that HEAD section to load the contents into the DIV:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#MainBack').load('html-content-file.html');    
});
</script>
```

Example of the contents of html-content-file.html:

```
  <a class="brand" href="#">240Dots</a>
  <div class="navbar-content">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Inicio</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="quienes-somos.html">Quienes Somos</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="servicios.html">Servicios</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contactar.html">Contactar</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

More info: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load

Comment: There's an error in your code:
`<script> src="http://...` should be `<script src="http://...`. Important little detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = 'HTML SOURCE'` with a javascript event. This works completely without problems.

Comment: How would one load the "HTML SOURCE"?

Comment: @lupus-ossorum Over an AJAX request