# How to / Should I use EJS templates on Electron?

Tags: electron, ejs

I am experimenting with Electron and attempting to use EJS for layouts and partials. I can not get it to work trying the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280011/how-to-use-html-templates-in-electron-framework) and can not find anything better. I am new to node and it all seems a bit overly complex to setup. It makes me wonder whether I should be using EJS and templates for native app development in the first place..?

Comment: Can you not use Express and Express#Router to render the EJS templates with a context? You could then just open links with your buttons, but the user would never see the link.

Comment: @Crowes I could.. but this approach feels like a hack for a desktop app. I am just wondering about common ways of achieving this kind of functionality.

Comment: Hack? Electron is ECF with Node, so a browser. You're running websites inside the `BrowserWindow`` you instantiate. using Express, Angular, or Vue routing would not be a hack.

Comment: @Crowes Articles like [this](https://blog.samuelattard.com/using-express-inside-electron/) confused me. That is why I am asking for common strategies to get a sense of what other people are doing.

Comment: The `electron-router` package mentioned seems to be a good call.

Answer (score 4):

install **ejs-electron** using **npm install ejs-electron** and import ejs-electron in main window page like

const ejse = require('ejs-electron')

and use your ejs page like

mainWindow.loadFile('client/components/home/index.ejs')

use constant ejse if you want but it is necessary to install and import ejs-electron if you want ejs as atemplate.
you can follow the link [ejs-electron](http://ejse.data('key')%20--%20Retrieve%20the%20value%20of%20'key'%20in%20the%20current%20data%20set.%20ejse.data('key',%20'val')%20--%20Set%20'key'%20to%20'val'in%20the%20current%20data%20set.%20ejse.data(%7Bkey:%20'val'%7D)%20--%20Replace%20the%20current%20data%20set%20with%20a%20new%20one%20containing%20%7Bkey:%20'val'%7D)